# How To Negate A Boolean In A Pipeline?

Tags: elixir

Consider the following code:

```
defmodule T do
  def does_not_contain?(s, t) do
    s |> not(String.contains?(t))
  end
end
```

This gives the following error on compilation:

```
** (CompileError) iex:3: undefined function not/2
```

I also tried a construct like this:

```
defmodule T do
  def does_not_contain?(s, t) do
    s |> String.contains?(t) |> not
  end
end
```

That gives me this error:

```
** (SyntaxError) iex:4: unexpected token: end
```

I can do something like this which works:

```
defmodule T do
  def does_not_contain?(s, t) do
    does_contain = s |> String.contains?(t)
    not(does_contain)
  end
end
```

But it's quite appealing to try to keep the whole thing in the pipeline.  Is there any way to negate a boolean within the pipeline?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you use the fully qualified version of the function then you can use it in a pipeline:

```
iex(1)> true |> Kernel.!
false
iex(2)> true |> Kernel.not
false
```