# Check boolean condition with pipe operator?

Tags: elixir

Imagine the result of a pipe operation is a value I want to check in a boolean condition

```
def isGreaterThanZero? do
  num =
    |> some pipe which returns a number
  num > 0
end
```

Can I somehow refactor this to:

```
def isGreaterThanZero? do
  some pipe which returns a number
  |> Boolean.true(&1 > 0)
end
```

Comment: Potentially related question: [How To Negate a Boolean in a Pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201156/how-to-negate-a-boolean-in-a-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Kernel.>/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#%3E/2) is a generic function.

So you can use `Kernel.>(1,2)`.

```
def isGreaterThanZero? do
  num =
    |> some pipe which returns a number
    |> Kernel.>(0)
end
```

Comment: Nice, didnt know there Kernel operators